# About Dropdown selected value in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have three dropdown for Day,Month,Year

in each dropdown I added these lines of code :

```
ddlDay.Items.FindByValue(System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Day.ToString()).Selected = true;
```

but i want to show it as

```
DD selected as in dropdown Day
MM selected as in dropdown Month
YYYY selected as in dropdown Year
```

I also use :

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMonth" runat="server" class="form-control">                     
   <asp:ListItem Value="-1">MM</asp:ListItem>   
</asp:DropDownList>
```

these lines to each drop down but it not working

Pls help me.Thanks in Advance

Comment: Could clarify your question further? It is unclear what your desired behaviour is.

Comment: on form load i get the previous day,month,year in my 3 dropdown,but what i want is on formload three dropdown display default as Day,Month,Year as in words...also the year ,month and date that i have set already too...